# gitlab: How to not break old gitolite urls

Tags: git, gitolite, gitlab

I'm in the process of migrating from gitolite to gitlab.

My original repositories had urls like: `git@dev.example.com:project-gui` and `git@dev.example.com:project-libs`.

Gitlab has forced me to use urls like: `git@dev.example.com:project/gui` and `git@dev.example.com:project/libs`.

I don't want to force changes in documentation and remote url in existing clones.

Is there a way I can either allow top-level repos, a proxy or perhaps  URL redirection for these repos?

Comment: Gitlab doesn't seem to want to allow this: http://feedback.gitlab.com/forums/176466-general/suggestions/4325752-bring-back-global-namespaces

Answer (score 2):

We ended up solving this by using the `git` user account on that server to host read-only repositories the mirrored the gitlab ones.

We then used the `gitlab` user for running gitlab.